# subset using R language

Tags: r, apply

I have 2 tables

In the first table, I have two columns. In the first colum , the values run from 1 to 2 million (call them x). In the second column, I have random numbers (call them y) .

In the second table , I have two columns. In the first colum , I have the same x values, but they do not run from 1 to 2 million instead they are in random increasing order like 222 , 249 , 562 .. and so on. In the second column, I have random numbers (call them z) .

Now, I am trying to add a third column to my second table with the y values from first table.I decided to use apply . But, you can use join or merge -- whichever is more efficient.  Here x value connects the y and the z.

To start with a minimal data, you can use this code:

```
t1 <- cbind(1:20, sample(100:999, 20, TRUE))
t2 <- rbind(c(2, 4), c(6, 12), c(17, 18))
apply(t2, 1, function(...) )
```

Could you help me to fill the ... blanks.

The output should be of the form:

```
2    4    --
6    12   --
17   18   --
```

Comment: Why do you need to use apply? Why not merge or join from plyr?

Comment: ok, we can also use join or merge

Comment: I am trying this merge(t2,t1, by = intersect(names(x),..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this meet your requirements?

```
require(plyr)

t1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(1:20, sample(100:999, 20, TRUE)))
t2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(c(2, 4), c(6, 12), c(17, 18)))

t3 <- join(t2, t1, type = "left", by = "V1")
t3
> t3
  V1 V2  V2
1  2  4 779
2  6 12 898
3 17 18 903
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `merge` for this:

```
merge(as.data.frame(t2), as.data.frame(t1), by='V1')
  V1 V2.x V2.y
1  2    4  751
2  6   12  298
3 17   18  218
```